# Exiting from a Batch Script

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, automation

I have a batch script which I am using to run a C# application with command line arguments 
like :  application.exe arg1 arg2 arg3.

How can I exit from the batch script on some condition occured due to execution of application.exe arg1 arg2 arg3.

```
example my batch script looks like this 
:start
echo cycle %count%
application.exe arg1 arg2
application.exe arg3 arg4
..
..
..
..
some 10 commands
count = count+1
if %count% < 10 goto start
:endloop
```

depending on some condition I want to exit from the batch script (say application.exe arg6 arg7 which calls some functionXX() on the return value of functionXX()?

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Two questions: (1) Do you want to know how to make your batch script do something special when your C# script calls a particular function (which... I mean, there's no easy way to make that happen. You're far better off changing the C#)? and (2) What on earth does this question have to do with functional programming?

Comment: (1) Yes correct , somethign special is "Exiting" from the batch Script                                                               (2) COrrecetd !

Comment: Try `exit /b` or `goto :eof` ; either should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should most likely use `exit /b` ([More info here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490902.aspx)) or `goto :eof` where `:eof` means *end of file*, both work here, it's just a matter of personal preference

**EDIT:** For the record, `exit /b` and `goto :eof`, if in a subroutine, will only exit the subroutine

**EDIT #2:** `exit /b` can cause problems, so do use `goto :eof` IF it is a subroutine, if not, you should be fine